# R - How to add column of data frame as column of another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 data frames, the dimensions are like this:

```
dim (df1)
[1] 1418    1

dim (df2)
[1] 1418    1
```

So I only have 1 column in each DF and the same number of rows. I want to add the 2nd data frame to the first one so that I have a dim of 1418 rows and 2 columns.

I did this:

```
df1[,2] = df2[,1] # and this:
dfnew = merge (df1, df2)
```

But it doesnt work. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: `cbind(df1, df2)`

Comment: Oh dear, so easy..I thought that is adding rows under existing columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `merge` function requires that you have a shared column between the `data.frame`s that you're combining.  In your case, with only one column each, this couldn't possibly be the case.

As @Lyngbakr noted in the comments, you want to use `cbind` which will literally concatenate the two together.  For example, `dfnew = cbind(df1,df2)`

`cbind` will work on vectors, `data.frame` and `data.frame` like objects as well as matrices.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1$addl_col<-df2$col
```

This should work as long as the lengths are the same (which is implied by nrow(df1)==nrow(df2)

You can also use dplyr, which has advantages of performance and chaining (and avoids some redundant syntax). Two options:

```
df<-mutate(df,addl_col=df2$'col')
df<-df%>%mutate(addl_col=df2$'col')
```

Although this is a bit unorthodox for dplyr, as seen by the necessity of the quotation marks.